# How to calculate the Fourier transform of $e^\frac{-|t|}{T}$?

Tags: fourier-transform

Let 
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}e^{-\frac{|t|}{T}}&if&|t| \lt T \\0&if &|t| \ge T\end{cases}$$

I believe I have to separate this into three integrals, from $-\infty$ to -T, from -T to T, and from T to $\infty$. But I get confused with the absolute value, and how to separate that.

Comment: It should be 4 integrals (divide the case [-T,T] into [-T,0],[0,T]). The result you should find is proportional to a  (sinc^2) (cardinal sine squared)

Comment: One way is the convolution theorem, since $f(t)=\text{rect}_T(t) e^{-|t|/T}$. That's convenient, since if memory serves these have the sinc function and the absolute value function as their respective Fourier transforms. Assuming that's true, all that remains is to convolve them.

Comment: My recollection wasn't quite right: $e^{-|t|/T}$ has a Lorentzian function as its Fourier transform. (See entry 207 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions) for reference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define the unitary Fourier transform of $f$:
\begin{align}
\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)&:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f\left(t\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}\mathrm{d}t.
\end{align}
We compute:
\begin{align}
\hat{f}\left(\omega\right)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-T}^{T}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\left|t\right|}{T}}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-T}^{0}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{t}{T}}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{T}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t}{T}}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-T}^{0}\mathrm{e}^{\left(\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega\right)t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{T}\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega\right)t}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\left(\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega\right)t}}{\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega}\right]_{t=-T}^{t=0}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega\right)t}}{\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega}\right]_{t=0}^{t=T}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\frac{2\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega\right)\frac{T}{2}}}{\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega}\sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{T}-\mathrm{i}\omega\right)\frac{T}{2}\right)-\frac{2\mathrm{i}\mathrm{e}^{-\left(\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega\right)\frac{T}{2}}}{\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega}\sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{T}+\mathrm{i}\omega\right)\frac{T}{2}\right)\right].
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: You are welcome!